# How to filter and group data into 2 categories (class variables)?

Tags: angular, typescript

So I have this method:

```
getProducts() {
this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(products => {
  this.products = products;
});
```

Everything works great, so these are the 'products':

- 0: {code: 'Product1', order: 1, description: 'Description', category: 'categoryone', price: 1500, …}
- 1: {code: 'Product1', order: 2, description: 'Description', category: 'categoryone', price: 1000, …}
- 2: {code: 'Product2', order: 1, description: '', category: 'categorytwo', price: 1199, …}
- 3: {code: 'Product2', order: 2, description: '', category: 'categorytwo', price: 2999, …}
- 4: {code: 'Product2', order: 3, description: '', category: 'categorytwo', price: 7999, …}

So what I'm trying is to filter and group that products into two class variables, for example categoryOne and categoryTwo and then display that data, but I don't know how.

Comment: this is not a well asked question, if the products are an array of objects, you can easily search for how to filter an array of objects. Here is for asking technical questions for which it is hard to find an answer, not a teacher assistant platform. Pease first learn the basics !

Comment: do you know the category names before calling the getProducts method?

Comment: @Mr.Stash yes, categoryone and categorytwo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the category names and products is an array you can just loop over the array and use if conditions to assign the product to their respective variables

```js
categoryoneProducts = []
categorytwoProducts = []

getProducts() {
  this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(products => {
    this.products = products;

    this.categoryoneProducts = []
    this.categorytwoProducts = []

    this.products.forEach(product => {

      if (product.category === 'categoryone') {
        categoryoneProducts.push(product)
      } else if (product.category === 'categorytwo') {
        categorytwoProducts.push(product)
      }
    })
  });
}
```